# Instance member 'getPopularProductList' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, api, dart, backend

I have been trying to called a method from another dart file from below file..but it's showing Instance member 'getPopularProductList' can't be accessed using static access.

import 'package:food_delivery/data/repository/popular_product_repo.dart';
import 'package:food_delivery/models/product_models.dart';

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';



class PopularProductController extends GetxController {
  final PopularProductRepo popularProductRepo;
  PopularProductController({required this.popularProductRepo});
   List<dynamic> _popularProductList = [];
   List<dynamic> get popularProductList =>_popularProductList;

  Future<void> getPopularProductList() async {
    Response response = await PopularProductRepo.getPopularProductList();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      _popularProductList = [];
      _popularProductList.addAll(Product.fromJson(response.body).products);
      update();
    }
    else{

    }
  }
```

}

The method was defined below here..

```
    import 'package:food_delivery/data/api/api_client.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class PopularProductRepo extends GetxService {
  final ApiClient apiClient;popular_product_repo
  PopularProductRepo({required this.apiClient});

  Future<Response> getPopularProductList() async {
    return await apiClient.getData("http://mvs.bslmeiyu.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: you can access from static function or variable to static, but cant access static to non static. if you not that function or variable not static, you must create instance to access it.

Comment: Would adding ```static``` in front of ```Future<void> getPopularProductList()``` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because `PopularProductRepo.getPopularProductList()` is the way you would access the method if it was defined as a static method, you want to use the instance of the class to access the method instead, so instead us `popularProductRepo.getPopularProductList()`